# How to write Relational Algebra

Tags: sql

Here the relation:  WORKS(emp_name, company_name,salary)

Q. Write an expression Relational Algebra to find the company name that has the highest number of employee.

I tried to solve it in many ways but not finding the correct way.

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a query which should work across most RDBMS:

```
SELECT company_name
FROM WORKS
GROUP BY company_name
HAVING COUNT(*) = SELECT MAX(empCount) FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS empCount
    FROM WORKS
    GROUP BY company_name
) t
```

If you are using MySQL, SQL Server, or any database which has a `LIMIT` keyword (or something like it), then the query gets easier:

```
SELECT company_name, COUNT(*) AS empCount
FROM WORKS
GROUP BY company_name
ORDER BY empCount DESC
LIMIT 1
```